# Retrieve every logo urls of a channels list

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, twitch

I have a list of string as input. Each string is an existing Twitch channel name.

I want to use the [Twitch API](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api) to retrieve the urls for the logo of each channel.

I have tried using the [GET /streams](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/streams.md#get-streams) method with a comma-separated list of my channels as the `channel` parameter. This works but only partially, since the `GET /streams` only retrieves information for *online* channels.

I have also tried using the [GET /channel](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/channels.md#get-channel) method. This works all the time even if the channel is offline, but I have to do one query PER channel, which is very bad performance-wise.

Is there a way to achieve what I need efficiently (retrieve every logo urls for a given channels list)?

Comment: Do you want all the channels that you follow?

Comment: no it is an arbitrary list of channels (few hundreds :| )

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is a way to do that. You could get everything you can from `GET /streams` and for any that you don't find there, you could use `GET /channel`

Comment: @AnotherDev do you happen to know the Twitch API query rate limit..? Would I be allowed to fire 250 `GET /channel` at once for example?

Comment: [Not totally clear](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API#rate-limits), but maybe if you have a client id, there is no limit.